# How do I make two scroll bars share the same LEFT position of a red ball in a diagonal graph in HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I have problem in html and css. I need to make a graph in which the red ball goes up and down diagonally and it must follow the X position of the blue line (this element only moves to the right or left). The problem is that scroll bar 1 and 2 share the left position of the red ball... So it ends up buggy and they go back to the position in percentage of their respective scroll bar.
How do I make both of them share the same LEFT position of the red ball?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    const scrollBar1 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar1");
    const scrollBar2 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar2");
    const scrollBar3 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar3");
    const scrollBar4 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar4");
    const scrollBar5 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar5");
    const scrollBar6 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar6");
  
    const redBall = document.getElementById("red-ball");
    const blueLine = document.getElementById("blue-line");

    let leftBall

    scrollBar1.addEventListener("input", function() {
      // Verifica se o valor da scroll bar 1 foi alterado
      if (scrollBar1.value !== scrollBar1.previousValue) {

        const xPercentage = (scrollBar1.value - 100) / (200 - 100);
      const xPosition = xPercentage * 100;
      leftBall = xPosition
      redBall.style.left = `${leftBall}%`;
      
  
      // Atualiza a posição da bola vermelha na vertical (scroll bar 1)
      const yPercentage = (scrollBar1.value - 100) / (200 - 100);
      const yPosition = yPercentage * 100;
      redBall.style.top = `${yPosition}%`;

      console.log(redBall.style.left)

      }
    });

    scrollBar2.addEventListener("input", function() {
      // Verifica se o valor da scroll bar 1 foi alterado
      if (scrollBar2.value !== scrollBar2.previousValue) {

        const blueLinePercentage = (scrollBar2.value - 400) / (0 - 400);
        const blueLinePosition = blueLinePercentage * 100;
        //leftBall = blueLinePosition
        blueLine.style.left = `${80 - blueLinePosition}%`;
        redBall.style.left = `${100-blueLinePosition}%`;
        console.log(redBall.style.left)
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

#chart {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#red-ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#black-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#blue-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#x-axis {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#y-axis {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -30px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.axis-label {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.scroll-bar {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.scroll-bar input[type="range"] {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.scroll-bar-value {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Gráfico de Demanda por Carne Moída</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Gráfico de Demanda por Carne Moída</h1>
    <div id="chart">
      <div id="red-ball"></div>
      <div id="black-line"></div>
      <div id="blue-line"></div>
      <div id="x-axis">
        <span class="axis-label">6,292</span>
        <span class="axis-label">10,292</span>
        <span class="axis-label">14,292</span>
      </div>
      <div id="y-axis">
        <span class="axis-label">90</span>
        <span class="axis-label">140</span>
        <span class="axis-label">190</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar1" min="100" max="200" value="150">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value1" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar2" min="0" max="400" value="200">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value2" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar3" min="100" max="300" value="200">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value3" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar4" min="100" max="400" value="180">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value4" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar5" min="10" max="200" value="30">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value5" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar6" min="0" max="200" value="100">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value6" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Managing all the variables in the same callback made the issue clearer for me.

This was not easy, but I think I got it working:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    const scrollBar1 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar1");
    const scrollBar2 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar2");
    const scrollBar3 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar3");
    const scrollBar4 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar4");
    const scrollBar5 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar5");
    const scrollBar6 = document.getElementById("scroll-bar6");
  
    const redBall = document.getElementById("red-ball");
    const blueLine = document.getElementById("blue-line");
    
    scrollBar1.addEventListener("input", updatePos);
    scrollBar2.addEventListener("input", updatePos);
    
    function  updatePos(){
        const xPercentage = (scrollBar1.value - 100) / (200 - 100);
        const xPosition = xPercentage * 100;
        
        let leftBall = xPosition+20;
        
        // Atualiza a posição da bola vermelha na vertical (scroll bar 1)
        const yPercentage = (scrollBar1.value - 100) / (200 - 100);
        const yPosition = yPercentage * 100;
      
        const blueLinePercentage = (scrollBar2.value - 400) / (0 - 400);
        const blueLinePosition = blueLinePercentage * 100;
        
        leftBall -= blueLinePosition-30;
        
        redBall.style.top = `${yPosition}%`;
        redBall.style.left = `${leftBall}%`;
        blueLine.style.left = `${80 - blueLinePosition}%`;
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

#chart {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#red-ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#black-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#blue-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#x-axis {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#y-axis {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -30px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.axis-label {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.scroll-bar {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.scroll-bar input[type="range"] {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.scroll-bar-value {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Gráfico de Demanda por Carne Moída</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Gráfico de Demanda por Carne Moída</h1>
    <div id="chart">
      <div id="red-ball"></div>
      <div id="black-line"></div>
      <div id="blue-line"></div>
      <div id="x-axis">
        <span class="axis-label">6,292</span>
        <span class="axis-label">10,292</span>
        <span class="axis-label">14,292</span>
      </div>
      <div id="y-axis">
        <span class="axis-label">90</span>
        <span class="axis-label">140</span>
        <span class="axis-label">190</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar1" min="100" max="200" value="150">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value1" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar2" min="0" max="400" value="200">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value2" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar3" min="100" max="300" value="200">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value3" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar4" min="100" max="400" value="180">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value4" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar5" min="10" max="200" value="30">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value5" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
      <input type="range" id="scroll-bar6" min="0" max="200" value="100">
      <span id="scroll-bar-value6" class="scroll-bar-value"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```